# Was Stevenson's Captain Smollett named after Tobias Smollett?

Tags: character-analysis, inspiration, name-significance, robert-louis-stevenson, treasure-island

The captain of the *Hispaniola* in Robert Louis Stevenson's *Treasure Island* is a man named [Alexander Smollett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Alexander_Smollett). There's also a Scottish writer named [Tobias Smollett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobias_Smollett), and there's [speculation](https://books.google.com/books?id=LmZaDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=was+captain+Smollett+in+Treasure+Island+named+after+Tobias+Smollett?&source=bl&ots=pjQZHP8uH9&sig=EdGUplcAARci_kv8OkWSjnzV9oI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj57aeLzc_bAhUL4IMKHbyKCqYQ6AEIVDAD#v=onepage&q=was%20captain%20Smollett%20in%20Treasure%20Island%20named%20after%20Tobias%20Smollett%3F&f=false) that the fictional Smollett was named after him. What is the evidence for this, beyond the shared surname?

Comment: You should summarize the jist of your cited explanatory note 51: both Smollets were nautical,  both were sardonic.

Comment: @kimchilover Oh, I didn't even twig that connection. It's been too long since I read Treasure Island for me to remember Captain Smollett's personality clearly. Actually, those two connections sound like material for an answer :-)